# Regla Regex para que separe los corres

Tags: regex, email, g-suite

Estoy creando una regla Regex para que identifique ciertos correos.

La regla es la siguiente:

```
(\W|^)[\w.+\-]{0,25}@([a-z]{2}\.midominio\.com)(\W|$)
```

Usando esta regla se aplicacaría a este correo: **midireccion@es.midominio.com**

La principio con esta regla nos bastaba, ahora necesitamos que separe todos los correos menos los de un subdominio

Para este caso, si cogemos por ejemplo España (es), esta regla no debería funcionar con este correo: **midireccion@es.midominio.com**

¿Cómo podría hacer una regla para que valide todos los correos menos los de subdomino España (es)?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(\W|^)[\w.+\-]{0,25}@((?!es)[a-z]{2}\.midominio\.com)(\W|$)`

El truco está en `(?!es)`, si la expresión siguiente `[a-z]{2}` matchea ésta, entonces no se produce un match.

Puedes encontrar más información si buscas `negative lookahead`.

Comment: ¡Ostras! Muchas gracias, Alex. Sí había leído sobre negative lookahead, pero no conseguí que funcionara correctamente. Por tu respuesta, puedo ver que era la sintaxis.